# Is it possible to export data from one website into another without an API?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, export

I am very new to web development (basic JS, Node, Express, Mongoose and MongoDB knowledge) and have an idea for a web app.  My app would act like a spreadsheet, taking user inputs and generating an output.  Then when the user elects to export data to the third party site, my app would ask for third party site authentication, login, and post the data to the third party site.  The third party site does not have an API and I have not found terms and conditions regarding the fair use of the site, which I've read can be a show stopper.

My question: is it possible and feasible to post to a third party site, assuming I have user authentication, but without an API?

If so, would you recommend a particular tool I can learn to handle the job?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: If you are not the owner of the third party site, I think you can't be able to post content without an API, unless that website have another mechanism to accomplish this functions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to communicate or share data with a third party site, it should provide you an end point which http API is one of most used way . If the 3rd  site is not providing an interface there is no legit way to communicate unless a hack which is not recommended .